# error pattern match map ^key (key with pin) [Elixir]

Tags: elixir

I'm studying some tutorial about elixir

but I have a problem finding the solution in this example

```
nola = %{ name: "New Orleans", founded: 1718 }
field = "founded"
%{^field: city_founded} = nola
** (SyntaxError) iex:14: syntax error before: field


#I try with atom
field = :founded
%{^field: city_founded} = nola
** (SyntaxError) iex:15: syntax error before: field

#with Charlist
field = 'founded'
%{^field: city_founded} = nola 
** (SyntaxError) iex:16: syntax error before: field
```

In the manual it show that this is correct, but it didn't work in my
IEx 1.6.5 (compiled with OTP 19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close!

Please try this instead:

```
nola = %{ name: "New Orleans", founded: 1718 }
field = :founded
%{^field => city_founded} = nola # pay atention to this line
city_founded => 1718
```

**Explanation:**

Maps can have keys either as Strings or atoms, so these are valid maps:

```
m1 = %{"my_key" => "foo"}
m2 = %{my_key: "foo"}
```

And you can access values like:

```
m1["my_key"] # => "foo"
m2[:my_key] # => "foo"
```

As per @mudasobwa's suggestion, to clarify further, Strings (or, more accurately - binaries) are not interchangeable with atoms, thus you won't be able to obtain values from the maps if used wrongly:

```
m1[:my_key] # => nil
m2["my_key"] # => nil
```

That means once you set up your field to be an atom:

```
field = :founded
```

you need to use it in pattern matching with `=>` syntax:

```
%{^field => city_founded} = nola
```

Because, if you try to use syntax with `:`

```
%{^field: city_founded} = nola
```

it will be invalid - your `field` is already an atom.

If this clarifies it a bit further, these two examples are equal:

```
%{my_key: "val1"}
%{"my_key": "val2"}
%{:my_key => "val3"}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is probably worth it to explicitly show that binaries and atoms are not interchangeable: `m1[:my_key] # => nil` and `m2["my_key"] # => nil`.

Comment: This is really good point @mudasobwa! I'll add this straight away!

Comment: Very good explanation, I right now understand why I was getting error in that part of code, thanks for your great explanation @PawełDawczak!